# Extending Activity or ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which includes support for Android Lolipop and earlier versions.

Based on [Maintaining compatibility](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) documentation i planned to use ActionBarActivity with AppCompact for non Lolipop devices and FragmentActivity with material for Lolipop devices.

I created two different value folders.

Now the problem is how should i extend my Activity class with

```
MyActivity extends Activity
```

or

```
MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity
```

If i use Activity. It crashes on earlier android version and saying me to add ActionBarActivity and the vice versa happens for lolipop

EDIT ------

values-21

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
```

values

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: do you have any themes defined

Comment: If something crashes, post a stack trace.

Comment: Compile your project with API 16. It will tell you what you cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

You extend ActionBarActivity if you'll be using the ActionBar on api s lower then 11 for support for api >=7 check out http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Also it can be a source of confusion but when you use `ActionBarActivity`
your theme must be a child of one of `Theme.AppCompact` descendents such as

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompact">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/accent_1</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#f00</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/accent_1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/accent_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#f00</item>

</style>
```

The non prefixed `android:`provide the Material theme compatibility that you talked you want for users of `< API 21 (Lollipop)`

Comment: Check the new documentation released by google. In which they are introducing material design along with AppCompact for API >= 14 to API <=19. https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html

Comment: Ok I've checked it I didn't read anything related to ActionBarActivity so I assume what I stated remains effective use ActionBarActivity for supporting ActionBar in api >=7, post the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Extend `ActionBarActivity` and use `Theme.AppCompat` - so your style theme will be this only values-21

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

values

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
```

try this and let me know if it works

NOTE1: ive not tried it, and im conjuring from a wide range of thoughts

ps; yes ive read the documentation..

Comment: i tried but and it works the problem is AppCompat has only some widgets of material design... Example Material ProgressBar is not present in AppCompat

Comment: from how i understand you is you Material progressBar ryt? well as of now it is not available the onli widgets available is 
    EditText
    Spinner
    CheckBox
    RadioButton
    SwitchCompat
    CheckedTextView
so its a matter of time.. have i understood you enough to answer you? let me know bro..@PrinceVegeta

Comment: yes you have understood me. using AppCompat for Lolipop devices is restricting the developer to have the complete power of Material. So i want Lolipop users to get complete Material effect and non lolipop user get partial Material effect using AppCompact..

Comment: I can ignore AppCompat and extends my BaseActivity with FragmentActivity. This works fine.. Lolipop will automatically use Material properties and non lolipop will use Holo properties. But i dont want this solution.

Comment: oh ok great..well if you've solved it then its ok..@PrinceVegeta