# How to display Menu Items overflow android

Tags: android

I want to display my menu items on ActionBar with android
I found some samples but It was not what I wanted

Menu should be similar picture below(Overflow Icon or text)
[image]

My menu.xml is :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:visible="true"
    android:title="Refresh"/>
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="Settings">
<item
    android:id="@+id/mapMenu"
    android:title="map menu" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/favMenu"
    android:title="favorite" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/listMenu"
    android:title="List Menu" />  
</item>
```

and my android code :

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.getTitle() + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mapMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.favMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    case R.id.listMenu:
        // do something
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some Android versions or on some devices, I think, the overflow icon would not be displayed, and you would have to press the menu button on the phone.

With what you have at the moment, the overflow icon would be displayed on some devices and not on some others.

## **Using the support library**

If you really want to have an overflow icon, you could use the appcompat support library for Android 5.0.

To do that, add this into your `build.gradle` file, under `dependencies`:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
```

Also, you need to extend `ActionBarActivity` in your activity instead of `Activity`.

And in `styles.xml`, make sure your parent theme has the prefix `Theme.AppCompat`.

You can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449454/extending-activity-or-actionbaractivity).

Comment: I'm iranian too, Can I get your email please?

Answer (score 0):

Try **android:showAsAction="never"** for item which you want to show in overflow menu . I think this is what you want.